# If Goldbach's conjecture G is undecidable in PA, then can we prove $\mathbb N\models G$?

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory, peano-axioms, incompleteness, nonstandard-models

Suppose Goldbach's conjecture $G$ is undecidable in first-order Peano arithmetic, $\sf{PA}$. That would mean there are models in which $G$ is true and other in which it is false. But intuitively, this would make $G$ "true" because there could not exist a counterexample proving $G$ false. Our intuition of "true arithmetic" can be formalized by fixing the model $\mathbb N$ in $\sf{ZFC}$ evaluating the truth of statements in $\mathbb N$. (Correct me if I'm wrong.)

**So does this mean that $G$ is provably true in $\mathbb N$?** This is where my understanding gets fuzzy. On the one hand, $\mathbb N$ is supposed to formalize our notion of "true" arithmetic, and since we can reason that undecidability $\implies$ true informally, I would expect this to translate into some formal statement about $\mathbb N$. On the other hand, I thought Gödel's incompleteness theorem carried more weight than "some statements about arithmetic are undecidable in $\sf{PA}$ and similar systems, so best to stick with $\mathbb N$ and then everything's fine."

Also, does the answer change if instead of merely assuming $G$ is undecidable, we assume it is *provably* undecidable (say, in $\sf{ZFC}$)?

Comment: If , say , ZFC can prove that Goldbach is undecidable in PA , then it also proves that it must be true (consistency of ZFC assumed). The reason : If Goldbach is false, then PA can prove this because there must be a counterexample PA can capture. If it is undecidable in ZFC , it is unlikely that we can prove exactly this in ZFC. It is however conjectured that the power of ZFC is enough to prove Goldbach (if it is true) although of course noone knows this.

Comment: For the Collatz conjecture , the situation is different. A divergent trajectory need not be provable in PA.

Answer (score 4):

If we could prove (in any given system) that $G$ is undecidable in PA, then we could prove there that it is true.  But it is quite possible that $G$ happens to be undecidable (and true) but there is no proof of that fact.

Comment: You're rep is going to overflow the Int32's they used, and it will eventually go back down to $0$, lol!   Keep up the great work, sir!

Comment: By "prove that it is true," do you mean "prove that it is true in $\mathbb N$"?

Comment: @WillG What else would he mean?

Answer (score 3):

It is a theorem of $\sf PA$ that

> $\lnot\mathsf{provable}_{\sf PA}(\mathsf{negation}(\ulcorner G\urcorner))\to G.$

When we work in set theory, "$G$" means (internally) the exact same thing as "$G$ is true in $\mathbb N$", so if you want to specify that by "true" you mean "true in $\mathbb N,$" that's okay, but maybe a little pedantic depending on the context. My point is there's no real difference between the above theorem of $\sf PA$ and the same theorem of $\sf ZFC$... certainly not something imbued by the fact that in $\sf ZFC$ we can talk about models.

> On the other hand, I thought Gödel's incompleteness theorem carried
> more weight than "some statements about arithmetic are undecidable in
> $\sf{PA}$ and similar systems, so best to stick with $\mathbb N$ and
> then everything's fine."

The canonical undecidable statement (the Gödel sentence) has the property that it is true, but not provable in $\mathsf{PA}.$ Of course, to prove this we need to use resources beyond $\sf PA$ (assuming $\sf Con(PA)$ will suffice).

I'm not sure what you mean by "stick with $\mathbb N$". But what the above suggests you *should* mean is "stick with stronger formal systems than the one you're studying if you want to prove statements it can't prove are true". And that's great until you're studying theories that are strong enough to formalize "all of math", like $\sf ZFC$ and we start wondering if more strengthening is justified. Is the Gödel sentence for $\sf ZFC$ true? Well, sure, but we're only justified in saying so inasmuch as we believe $\sf ZFC$ is consistent.

(And not to mention that not all the undecidability is of this simple "refutable if false" form of Goldbach / $\sf Con PA$ / Gödel sentence... but you asked about specifically what's given by Gödel's theorem, which is fair.)

Comment: Re: "Stick with $\mathbb N$," what I mean is, if you give PA the semantics/interpretation of standard $\mathbb N$, then the undecidable statements (of PA) become decidable? This means Gödel's theorem is toothless. Statements are only undecidable because PA is too weak and doesn't single out $\mathbb N$, but if we interpret it with $\mathbb N$, undecidability vanishes?

Comment: Or perhaps your last comment is to the effect of, "maybe so for the undecidable statements of similar form to Goldbach's conjecture and Gödel's sentence, but not for all of them."

Comment: @WillG If you mean we should substitute "true in $\mathbb N$" for "provable in PA", then indeed that miraculously decides literally every arithmetical statement, not just undecidable statements of Goldbach form. The problem is of course that we don't actually know what is "true in $\mathbb N$" and thus which way they're decided... for that we rely on mathematical proof formalizable in some suitable arithmetically sound system, like $\sf PA$ or $\sf ZFC$... and the incompleteness theorem implies any such system has arithmetical statements it can't decide.

Comment: @WillG Now of course you can say "but I know the Gödel sentence for PA is true in $\mathbb N$"... but what you really know is "if PA is is consistent, then its Gödel sentence is true in $\mathbb N$", so you can pass to a 'presumably sound' theory where it's provable ( $\sf PA + Con(PA)$ or $\sf ZFC$ if you feel like not beating around the bush). But whatever theory you go to, there will be a new Gödel sentence for that theory that is not provable in that theory, and you will need to assume the consistency of that theory if you want to prove it.

Comment: @WillG So assume $\sf Con ZFC$ (or the existence of inaccessible cardinals if you feel like not beating around the bush)... and the process can continue... But you'll always be effectively assuming more and more and will be at higher and higher risk of inconsistency. This the picture that the incompleteness theorem paints for us: we can't get 'lucky' and prove the consistency of very strong systems from very weak ones.

Answer (score 0):

You may be confusing theories and models.  The question is not really whether Goldbach's conjecture "$G$ is provable in $\mathbb N$", rather whether $G$ is provable in ZFC.  It could be that $G$ is undecidable in PA but provable in ZFC - which would imply by [Shoenfield Absoluteness Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absoluteness_(logic)#Shoenfield%27s_absoluteness_theorem) that $G$ is provable in ZF.  But of course we don't know that; $G$ may be undecidable in ZF, as well.

Comment: But how could $G$ be provable in ZFC, given that, if it is undecidable, then one can use ZFC to construct models where $G$ is true and others where $G$ is false?

Comment: @WillG, I think in your *comment* above you are confusing theories and models.  One can't "use ZFC to construct models".  If we happen to know that $G$ is undecidable in ZF, this would mean that there exist models where it is true and other models where it is false.  Such situations are not unusual; this is what happens for the continuum hypothesis, for example.

Comment: Aren't models typically constructed in ZFC? For example, one possible definition of $\mathbb N$ is "the set of elements that are contained in every inductive set, where inductive means ... (successor function, reference to $\varnothing$, etc)." I've seen this done in ZFC, though I'm sure it could be done in other set theories.

Comment: I think maybe I am misunderstanding the use of "provable in." Perhaps I should say "provable about." My question concerns whether we could prove that $G$ is true in (satisfied by?) the model $\mathbb N$ (and presumably, this proof itself would be done in ZFC or something like that, but that's not my main concern).

Comment: I updated the question title, and hopefully it now reflects what I was intending to ask, if I understand the meaning of $\mathbb N\models G$ correctly.

Comment: @WillG if we can prove in ZFC that it’s undecidable in PA then we can construct (in ZFC) models of PA where it’s false, and also prove it is true in $\mathbb N$ (which is to say that we can prove the ZFC version of the statement).

Comment: @WillG, your reference to "the model $\mathbb N$ in $\sf{ZFC}$" is still confused.  Every model of ZFC is going to have its own $\mathbb N$.  Some mathematicians would argue that there is no such thing as "the model $\mathbb N$".  Look up Hamkins' multiverse.

Comment: @WillG, indeed $\mathbb N$ can be defined as the smallest inductive set, but this will still be dependent on the model you are working in.

Comment: This is where my head starts to explode. I've tried reading Hamkins's paper "Satisfaction Is Not Absolute," but unfortunately I don't have enough background to understand it. For starters, does the fact that different models of ZFC have different theories of arithmetic contradict @spaceisdarkgreen 's claims (that if G was provably undecidable, we could prove it was true about $\mathbb N$ in ZFC)?

Comment: @WillG, well, space has excellent company of Goedel himself in being platonist about "the $\mathbb N$" with a definite article, but I have difficulty relating to such views.

Comment: Perhaps this is worth a separate post, but how are the last few comments reconciled with the fact that second-order PA is categorical, and satisfied by "$\mathbb N$," where presumably $\mathbb N$ is the standard thing constructed in ZFC without reference to any model of ZFC?

Comment: @WillG, the construction of $\mathbb N$ in ZFC is not some kind of mysterious or magical thing; as mentioned already, it is the smallest inductive set.  This depends on the model you are in.  $\mathbb R$ is also *categorical* as people like to point out, and also depends on which model you are in.  Hamkins is a talented expositor and I would suggest looking up some of his texts, to get a feeling for  how multiverse works, and a practical sense of how $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb R$ may not be unique.

Comment: @WillG I think a few things I've said in the comments to my question (e.g. talking about 'arithmetically sound' in a vacuum) might be reasonably construed as Platonist, but all I intended with "prove it is true in $\mathbb N$ in ZFC" was to prove the *internal* statement $(\mathbb N, +,\cdot)\models G$, i.e. the minimal inductive set with so and so operations defined satisfies $G$. (Which is why I equate it to "the ZFC version of $G$").

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen If we can prove $\mathbb N\models G$ in ZFC, and ZFC is a first-order theory, then isn't $\mathbb N\models G$ true in all models of ZFC, by Gödel's completeness theorem? This is why I don't understand MK's last few comments.

Comment: @WillG: What are you claiming exactly?  Are you claiming that provability of $G$ in ZFC should imply its provability in PA? I don't see that.

Comment: spaceisgreen is claiming something like $(ZFC\to \sf{undecidable}(G))\to(\mathbb N\models G)$ is provable in ZFC. I'm claiming if that and (hypothetically) $\sf{undecidable}(G)$ are provable in ZFC, then $\mathbb N\models G$ is true in all the $\mathbb N$'s in every model of ZFC, where $\mathbb N$ is defined in the usual way. It's not so much a claim as a question, based on my partial understanding of the subject.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen, did you claim that :-) ?

Comment: Too late to edit the comment now. I think space's claim is actually that $[\sf{ZFC}\vdash\sf{undecidable}_\text{PA}(G)]\to (\mathbb N\models G)$ is provable in ZFC. Where G is Goldbach's conjecture.

Comment: @WillG yes, it would be true in all models of ZFC. What’s the conflict?

Comment: Does the claim consist in saying that if ZFC can prove that $G$ is undecidable in PA, then ZFC could prove $G$?  That was pointed out by Robert Israel.  @spaceisdarkgreen, the comment in your *answer* seems slightly more technical, but are you saying that as well?

Comment: @MikhailKatz yes, I agree with that.

Comment: @MikhailKatz Or to correlate more with what WillG was going for I would also make the roughly equivalent claim that $$\mathsf{undecidable}_{\sf PA}(\ulcorner G\urcorner)\to \mathbb N\models \ulcorner G\urcorner$$ is a theorem of ZFC.

Comment: Perhaps I was misinterpreting Mikhail's two comments before my "head explode" comment. I thought the suggestion there was that some $\mathbb N$'s in some ZFC models might still not satisfy G, even if ZFC could prove G was undecidable in PA. Was this not your intended claim, Mikhail?

Comment: @WillG, the satisfiability of $G$ is detected by PA, as already pointed out in a comment by user Peter yesterday.  Incidentally, I appreciate your talking of $\mathbb N$ in the plural :-)  In the discussion above I mainly objected to the term "true arithmetic".  Experts know that they don't mean this literally when they use the term, but the term could be misleading.